# What is T1 in this circuit for 'Mains power failure alarm'?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design

I know it is a transformer, but is it a transformer that looks like an IC? Or just a regular step down transformer? (Transformer 12V (1A)). This will be built on a breadboard.

Also can I use 1n4007 for the full wave rectifier diodes?

I would also appreciate any feedback on this circuit.

[image]

Comment: "I know it is a transformer, but is it a transformer that looks like an IC? " so this is the question? I have never seen a transformer that looks like IC.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Maybe you have, but though it was IC :)

Comment: Don't put the transformer on a breadboard... find a screw mount one rather than PCB mount, and wire from it to the breadboard. Properly insulate all the mains wiring...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Now you have: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/h1012nl/pulse-electronics-corporation

Answer (score 8):

A little bit of googling would have helped here.

Here is the main page for the design: http://www.circuitstoday.com/mains-failure-alarm-circuit

And the relevant component choice notes:

- T1  can be  a 230V primary   6V secondary  500mA  transformer.
- B1 can be a 1A bridge.You can make the same using four 1N 4007 diodes.
- All capacitors are rated 25V.
- You can use any general purpose PNP transistor (like BC158,BC177 
  etc) as Q1.

Comment: What’s D2 and C2 for?

Comment: The circuit in the link is an old revision. @Studious posted the newest revision. 
In the link, D2 & C2 were supposed to be voltage smoothing after the rectifier, but as implemented, it would not work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes indeed that is a transformer. There are no markings to indicate, but most certainly it is a step down transformer. You could use the 1N4007 for the bridge as well, in fact it is way over rated for its use as D1 and D2.  Once this power fails the charged capacitor C1 supplies all the current for the buzzer K1. It likely will not last very long. To make it last longer you could use a super cap, but you'd have to regulate the voltage a lot better.

Comment: The schematic diagram shows "0" at the lower end of the secondary winding, and "6" at the upper end. That typically means a 6-volt winding.  And the primary side is clearly labeled "230V AC MAINS".

Answer (score 4):

The circuit shows that is a 230V to 6V stepdown transformer. Even the smallest power step-down transformer will be significantly larger than an integrated circuit. While there are some transformers that are potted in solid plastic blocks, and with pins out the bottom, they can't really be confused with integrated circuits as they are physically much larger and heavier (because of the iron core).

It is very unlikely that you can find a power transformer small enough to plug into a breadboard.  It may even be easier to substitute a 9V "wall wart" power source vs. building the entire power supply from scratch.  In most parts of the world it is not difficult to locate a surplus, redundant, or discarded power supply that could be used for this project.

The capacitance value of C1 will determine how long the piezo buzzer will sound before running out of energy.